# Controlling Layout of Multiple Dimple Charts in Shiny

Tags: shiny, rstudio, rcharts, dimple.js

I have been working on interactive population pyramids as per the examples here [Interactive Population Pyramids](http://walkerke.github.io/2014/06/rcharts-pyramids/) . Specifically, I have modified the code used for the Dimple.js implementation of a population pyramid. Within RStudio everything works well, however the end product would best be served as a Shiny App. When deploying to a Shiny app, it works well but I cannot control the size of the chart nor its placement. I intend to have 4 charts on the same page and the ideal layout would be for 4 quadrants (2 rows and 2 columns) each with its own visualization. At the moment am not seeing how I can control my chart sizes nor layout of my Dimple.js charts either via R or Dimple.js itself. Any help to this end would be greatly appreciated My current  code is as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(rcdimple)
library(curl)  #devtools::install_github("jeroenooms/curl")
library(plyr)  # for round_any
library(rCharts)

df <- read.csv(curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/data2.csv"))
agegroup_mapping <- read.csv(curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/agegroup.csv"))
df <- merge(df,agegroup_mapping,by.x="agegrp",by.y="agegroup")
# Max and minimum year to determine range of years to animate by
maxYear <- max(df$year)
minYear <- min(df$year)
# maximum and minimum values for population to determine x-axis
max_x <- round_any(max(df$n), 1000, f = ceiling)
min_x <- round_any(min(-1*df$n), 1000, f = floor)

getData <- function(startyr,endyear) {
  df <- subset(df,(year >= startyr & year <= endyear))
  return(df)
}

# DimpleJS pyramid

dPyramid <- function(startyear, endyear, colors=NULL) {
  #endyear = endyear + 3 #to test storyboard
  dat <- getData(startyear, endyear)
  dat$n <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', -1 * dat$n, 1 * dat$n)
  dat$gencode <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', 1, 2)

  d1 <- dimple(
    x = "n", 
    y = "agegrp", 
    groups = "sex", 
    data = dat, 
    type = 'bar')


  d1 <- yAxis(d1, type = "addCategoryAxis", orderRule = "ord")
  d1 <- xAxis(d1,type = "addMeasureAxis")
  d1 <- add_legend( d1,x = 60, y = 10, width = 700, height = 20, horizontalAlign = "right" )
  # Ensure fixed x-axis indepencent of year selected
  d1 <- xAxis(d1, overrideMax = max_x, overrideMin = min_x)

  if (!is.null(colors)){
    d1 <- colorAxis(
      d1,
      type = "addColorAxis", 
      colorSeries = "gencode", 
      palette = colors
    )
  }

  if (endyear - startyear >= 1) {
    d1 <- tack(d1, options = list( storyboard = "year" ) )
#     max_x <- round_any(max(dat$n), 1000, f = ceiling)
#     min_x <- round_any(min(dat$n), 1000, f = floor)
#     d1 <- xAxis(d1, overrideMax = max_x, overrideMin = min_x)
  }

  d1
}


#ui.R

# Define UI for application that draws a outcome pyramid
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Options"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("doAnimate", "Animate Pyramid",value = TRUE),
      tags$p("(Uncheck to select specific year)"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.doAnimate == false",
        selectInput(    
                  inputId = "startyr",
                  label = "Select Pyramid Year",
                  c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)),
                  width = 2
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "agegrp",
                  label = "Choose Age Group",
                  choices = c("0-4",
                              "5-9",
                              "10-14",
                              "15-19",
                              "20-24",
                              "25-29",
                              "30-34",
                              "35-39",
                              "40-44",
                              "45-49",
                              "50-54",
                              "55-59",
                              "60-64",
                              "65-69",
                              "70-74",
                              "75-79",
                              "80-84",
                              "85+"
                  ),
                  selected = "0-4")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated pyramid
    mainPanel("Multi-Panel Visualizations",
      fluidRow(style="height:300px;"
               ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot",height="100%", width="100%"))
               ,column(width = 6,showOutput("distPlot2","nvd3"))
      )
      ,fluidRow(style="height:300px;"
                ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot3",height="100%"))
                ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot4",height="100%"))
      )
    )
  )
))


# Define server logic required to draw a population pyramid
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({

    if(input$doAnimate){

    output$distPlot <- renderDimple({
      dPyramid(minYear, maxYear)
    })

  }else{

    output$distPlot <- renderDimple({
      startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
      # Start year and end year are equal we only want cross-sectional pyramid
      # for a single selected year
      dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
    })    
  }
  })
   # Top right quadrant, line-chart
  output$distPlot2 <- renderChart2({

    selection <- subset(df,mapping == input$agegrp)

    plot <- nPlot(n ~ year,
                  data = selection,
                  type = "lineChart",
                  group = "sex")

    # Add axis labels and format the tooltip
    plot$yAxis(axisLabel = "Population", width = 62)

    plot$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")

    plot$save("ac.html")
    return(plot)    

  })


  output$distPlot3 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
  output$distPlot4 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
})


#shinyApp(ui,server)
```

And the data it uses can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/data2.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by `rCharts`, but since `rcdimple` https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rcdimple was [released](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/3/18/week-11-dimple-as-htmlwidget) and benefits from the infrastructure of htmlwidgets, I would strongly recommend using it going forward.  Let me know if you would prefer to see the `rCharts` answer.

```
library(shiny)
library(rcdimple)
library(curl)  #devtools::install_github("jeroenooms/curl")
library(plyr)  # for round_any

df <- read.csv(curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/data2.csv"))
df$year <- df$ExpYear
df$sex <- df$Sex
df$agegrp <- df$AgeGroup

getData <- function(startyr,endyear) {
  df <- subset(df,(year >= startyr & year <= endyear))
  return(df)
}

# DimpleJS pyramid

dPyramid <- function(startyear, endyear, colors=NULL) {
  #endyear = endyear + 3 to test storyboard
  dat <- getData(startyear, endyear)
  dat$n <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', -1 * dat$n, 1 * dat$n)
  dat$gencode <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', 1, 2)

  d1 <- dimple(
    x = "n", 
    y = "agegrp", 
    groups = "sex", 
    data = dat, 
    type = 'bar')


  d1 <- yAxis(d1, type = "addCategoryAxis", orderRule = "ord")
  d1 <- xAxis(d1,type = "addMeasureAxis")
  d1 <- add_legend( d1,x = 60, y = 10, width = 700, height = 20, horizontalAlign = "right" )

  if (!is.null(colors)){
    d1 <- colorAxis(
      d1,
      type = "addColorAxis", 
      colorSeries = "gencode", 
      palette = colors
    )
  }

  if (endyear - startyear >= 1) {
    d1 <- tack(d1, options = list( storyboard = "year" ) )
    max_x <- round_any(max(dat$n), 1000, f = ceiling)
    min_x <- round_any(min(dat$n), 1000, f = floor)
    d1 <- xAxis(d1, overrideMax = max_x, overrideMin = min_x)
  }

  d1
}


#ui.R

# Define UI for application that draws a outcome pyramid
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Outcome Pyramid"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "startyr",
                  label = "Select Start Year",
                  c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014))
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated pyramid
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(style="height:300px;"
        ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot",height="100%"))
        ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot2",height="100%"))
      )
      ,fluidRow(style="height:300px;"
        ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot3",height="100%"))
        ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot4",height="100%"))
      )
    )
  )
))


# Define server logic required to draw a population pyramid
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
  output$distPlot2 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
  output$distPlot3 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
  output$distPlot4 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give that a go and let you know, but from an academic perspective I would love to know the rCharts solution too if you wouldn't mind? Thanks :-)

Comment: What version of R is rcdimple compatible with? Am getting `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rcdimple’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)`

Comment: `devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rcdimple")` got it!

Comment: OK have tried your code and it works a treat, it fits the screen. Am curious though at what has changed, apart from `dimpleOutput` in ui.R and `renderDimple` in server.R..whats going on behind the scenes which affected the change. Also my goal is to have 4 of these charts in a 2 x 2 layout, how would I achieve that?

Comment: htmlwidgets provide lots of powerful features for multiple contexts, such as browser, console, RStudio  Viewer, Shiny, etc., so we plan to port rCharts this direction.  I added an example of laying out multiple charts.  You might want to look at `shinyDashboard` also.

Comment: Thanks for this, it DID work, however :-) .... In your example you have 4 charts in a 2 X 2 grid, all dimple.js charts. As it turns out, in the top-right quadrant I want to place a NVD3 line chart which I developed in isolation as per [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316927/chart-not-rendering-with-shiny-r-and-nvd3 and would now like to incorporate it into this grid. However when incorporated, no graphs render, and Developer Tools in Chrome tells me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`... Can I not mix chart types (dimple and NVD3)?

Comment: I have edited the code in my original question to reflect how I currently have it set up

Comment: The issue here is that two versions of d3 are getting added to the dependencies and conflicting with each other.  Let me try to think through the best solution.

Comment: am not seeing where the edit has happened, please advise, where is the new code?

Answer (score 0):

For the `nvd3` to work, we will need to manually add the dependencies, since `rCharts` and `htmlwidgets` will both send over `d3.js` causing a conflict.  Since it is a different question than originally asked, I will add a new answer rather than revise my first.  Primary difference is adding `add_lib=F` to `showOutput` and then manually adding assets in `UI`.

```
library(shiny)
library(rcdimple)
library(curl)  #devtools::install_github("jeroenooms/curl")
library(plyr)  # for round_any
library(rCharts)

df <- read.csv(curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/data2.csv"))
agegroup_mapping <- read.csv(curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/agegroup.csv"))
df <- merge(df,agegroup_mapping,by.x="agegrp",by.y="agegroup")
# Max and minimum year to determine range of years to animate by
maxYear <- max(df$year)
minYear <- min(df$year)
# maximum and minimum values for population to determine x-axis
max_x <- round_any(max(df$n), 1000, f = ceiling)
min_x <- round_any(min(-1*df$n), 1000, f = floor)

getData <- function(startyr,endyear) {
  df <- subset(df,(year >= startyr & year <= endyear))
  return(df)
}

# DimpleJS pyramid

dPyramid <- function(startyear, endyear, colors=NULL) {
  #endyear = endyear + 3 #to test storyboard
  dat <- getData(startyear, endyear)
  dat$n <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', -1 * dat$n, 1 * dat$n)
  dat$gencode <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', 1, 2)

  d1 <- dimple(
    x = "n", 
    y = "agegrp", 
    groups = "sex", 
    data = dat, 
    type = 'bar')


  d1 <- yAxis(d1, type = "addCategoryAxis", orderRule = "ord")
  d1 <- xAxis(d1,type = "addMeasureAxis")
  d1 <- add_legend( d1,x = 60, y = 10, width = 700, height = 20, horizontalAlign = "right" )
  # Ensure fixed x-axis indepencent of year selected
  d1 <- xAxis(d1, overrideMax = max_x, overrideMin = min_x)

  if (!is.null(colors)){
    d1 <- colorAxis(
      d1,
      type = "addColorAxis", 
      colorSeries = "gencode", 
      palette = colors
    )
  }

  if (endyear - startyear >= 1) {
    d1 <- tack(d1, options = list( storyboard = "year" ) )
    #     max_x <- round_any(max(dat$n), 1000, f = ceiling)
    #     min_x <- round_any(min(dat$n), 1000, f = floor)
    #     d1 <- xAxis(d1, overrideMax = max_x, overrideMin = min_x)
  }

  d1
}


suppressMessages(
  singleton(
    addResourcePath(
      get_lib("nvd3")$name
      ,get_lib("nvd3")$url
    )
  )
)

#ui.R

# Define UI for application that draws a outcome pyramid
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$head(get_assets_shiny(get_lib("nvd3"))[-3]),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Options"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("doAnimate", "Animate Pyramid",value = TRUE),
      tags$p("(Uncheck to select specific year)"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.doAnimate == false",
        selectInput(    
          inputId = "startyr",
          label = "Select Pyramid Year",
          c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)),
        width = 2
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "agegrp",
                  label = "Choose Age Group",
                  choices = c("0-4",
                              "5-9",
                              "10-14",
                              "15-19",
                              "20-24",
                              "25-29",
                              "30-34",
                              "35-39",
                              "40-44",
                              "45-49",
                              "50-54",
                              "55-59",
                              "60-64",
                              "65-69",
                              "70-74",
                              "75-79",
                              "80-84",
                              "85+"
                  ),
                  selected = "0-4")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated pyramid
    mainPanel("Multi-Panel Visualizations",
              fluidRow(style="height:300px;"
                       ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot",height="100%", width="100%"))
                       ,column(width = 6,showOutput("distPlot2","nvd3",add_lib=F))
              )
              ,fluidRow(style="height:300px;"
                        ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot3",height="100%"))
                        ,column(width = 6,dimpleOutput("distPlot4",height="100%"))
              )
    )
  )
))


# Define server logic required to draw a population pyramid
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({

    if(input$doAnimate){

      output$distPlot <- renderDimple({
        dPyramid(minYear, maxYear)
      })

    }else{

      output$distPlot <- renderDimple({
        startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
        # Start year and end year are equal we only want cross-sectional pyramid
        # for a single selected year
        dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
      })    
    }
  })
  # Top right quadrant, line-chart
  output$distPlot2 <- renderChart2({

    selection <- subset(df,mapping == input$agegrp)

    plot <- nPlot(n ~ year,
                  data = selection,
                  type = "lineChart",
                  group = "sex",
                  height = 300,
                  width = 300 )

    # Add axis labels and format the tooltip
    plot$yAxis(axisLabel = "Population", width = 62)

    plot$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")

    plot$save("ac.html")
    return(plot)    

  })


  output$distPlot3 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
  output$distPlot4 <- renderDimple({
    startyear <- as.numeric(input$startyr)
    # Both arguments currently for the same thing, startyear, but eventually will want to 
    # process a range of years
    dPyramid(startyear, startyear)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Ok will give that a go, but seeing a couple of new things here which aren't too transparent as yet to me..`tags$head(get_assets_shiny(get_lib("nvd3"))[-3])` and `add_lib=F`; why the `[-3]` and why the `F`? Thanks

Comment: `[-3]` eliminates the `d3.js` dependency for `rCharts` `nvd3`.  To see it,  do `get_assets_shiny(get_lib("nvd3"))`.  `F` just says don't add the dependencies for `nvd3` since we need to do manually to exclude `d3`.  This is a hack until the `htmlwidgets` version of `rCharts` is released.  Then dependency conflicts will be automatically resolved.

Comment: Thanks! so the changes suggested DO work, however all the other surrounding graphs (dimple pyramids) get "vertically compressed" (in Chrome, havent checked in other browsers) for lack of a better word. I have ported the code over to `shinydashboard` and it seems to not suffer the same compression effect, so moving forward with `shinydashboard`. Thanks for the help :-) !

Comment: great to hear.  glad you are using.  please provide any additional feedback on rcdimple as it is very early in its life.

Comment: There are a couple of possible glitches am experiencing, but will post the code once I have completed the dashboard with some explanatory text, in the next couple of days. Thanks again