# Shiny and rCharts: I don't get it to work

Tags: r, shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts

I somehow don't get it to work. Nothing is displayed, but no error is shown. This is from my UI, so all libraries are loaded:

```
tags$head(
                        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style_mozilla_win.css"),
                        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href="nv.d3.css")
                      ),

                      HTML('
                           <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                           '),
```

....

```
mainPanel( 
                                              showOutput("SectorCharting", "nvd3")
                                            )
```

And from my server.R

```
output$SectorCharting<-renderChart({
      hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
      n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, 
                  type = 'multiBarChart')

      return(n1)
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same problem as here yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316927/chart-not-rendering-with-shiny-r-and-nvd3/29341555#29341555) and many before that, use Use `renderChart2` instead of `renderChart`.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

ui =pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test"),

  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("SectorCharting", "nvd3")
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {

  output$SectorCharting <-renderChart2({
    hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, 
                type = 'multiBarChart')
    return(n1)
  })
}


runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick...It is really hard to find any documentation on all of this unfortunately