# Shiny and rcdimple htmlwidget - how to resize to container?

Tags: r, shiny

This example didn’t seem to work with current code when resizing the browser window:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211664/controlling-layout-of-multiple-dimple-charts-in-shiny

Some starting code that doesn't resize as expected:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rcdimple)

## need to eventually plot points over bars, so...
##devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rcdimple@feature/layers")

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test_plot <- renderDimple(
    dimple(x = c('cyl', 'gear'), 
           y = 'mpg',
           groups = 'gear', 
           data = mtcars,
           width = '100%',
           type = 'bar')
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'test rcdimple'),

  dashboardSidebar(
    verbatimTextOutput('clicked_value')
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        width = 4,
        status = 'info',
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        title = 'test',
        dimpleOutput('test_plot')
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rcdimple_0.1         htmltools_0.2.6     
[3] htmlwidgets_0.5      shinydashboard_0.5.1
[5] shiny_0.12.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      lattice_0.20-33  digest_0.6.8    
 [4] mime_0.4         grid_3.2.2       R6_2.1.1        
 [7] xtable_1.7-4     jsonlite_0.9.17  magrittr_1.5    
[10] rstudioapi_0.3.1 tools_3.2.2      httpuv_1.3.3    
[13] yaml_2.1.13
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you are using `rcdimple`.  I believe you just need to move the `width = "100%"` to `ui`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rcdimple)

## need to eventually plot points over bars, so...
##devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rcdimple@feature/layers")

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test_plot <- renderDimple(
    dimple(x = c('cyl', 'gear'), 
           y = 'mpg',
           groups = 'gear', 
           data = mtcars,
           type = 'bar')
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'test rcdimple'),

  dashboardSidebar(
    verbatimTextOutput('clicked_value')
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        width = 4,
        status = 'info',
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        title = 'test',
        dimpleOutput('test_plot',width="100%")
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: That is one of the variations that I've tried. So, I tested that particular code in RStudio and a couple of browsers with no joy. Perhaps I'm on a version that doesn't quite support it? Based on another note and my need to plot points over the bars, I am using devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rcdimple@feature/layers")

Comment: I'm having issues with the widget automatically resizing when the size of the container changes. It's not until I change an input that causes the graph to be re-rendered does the graph fill the container.